# UITableView won't respond after presentModalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a custom class with a UITableView in it. If I present the class with:

```
MessageViewController *message = [[MessageViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MessageViewController" bundle: nil]; 
[self presentModalViewController: message animated: YES];
```

...the tableView won't respond to touch in the MessageViewController.

If I however use pushViewController, everything works fine..

```
MessageViewController *m = [[MessageViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"MessageViewController" bundle: nil]; 
[self.navigationController pushViewController: m animated:YES];
```

But I want to use presentModalViewController.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT

If I add the UITableView in code, it works... But not with interface builder..

Comment: Try using `self.parentViewController` as the message target for `presentModalViewController:animated:`. By the way, the two-argument method is deprecated, you should use `presentModalViewController:animated:completion` instead.

Comment: Maybe this link could help. It explains the difference between the two:
[link](https://discussions.apple.com/message/12484209?messageID=12484209#12484209?messageID=12484209)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the:

```
[self presentModalViewController: message animated: YES];
```

into

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController: message animated: YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this the modal is not showing up, I thinks because the parent view doesn´t have a navigation controller, don´t know cause I´m new in this ...